# How do I parse a string of URL query parameters into multiple columns of a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

Each row in my dataframe has a string containing some URL query parameters, e.g. `flt=promotionflag%3A1%3Borganicfilter%3AOrganic&sortBy=MOST_POPULAR`. The `flt` section could contain multiple parameters as in this example.

I want to parse this string into multiple columns like:

| flt_promotionflag | flt_organicfilter | sortBy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Organic | MOST_POPULAR |

There could be lots of different filters so I don't want to hardcode these as column names. If there is already a column with that filter name I want to put the value in the existing column, and if there there isn't a column with that filter name I want to create it.

I've written some code that creates a dictionary in the structure I want in a new column but I think that's probably an unnecessary step.

```
def createDict(string):
    try:
      d = dict(x.split("=") for x in string.strip("&").split("&"))
      if 'flt' in d:
        if '%3B' in d['flt']:
            d['flt'] = dict(x.split("%3A") for x in d['flt'].split("%3B"))
        else:
            d['flt'] = {d['flt'].split("%3A")[0] : 1}
      else:
        pass
      return d
    except:
      pass

df['Parsed params'] = df['URL Query Parameters'].apply(createDict)
```

How do I get the data I want in the right columns?

Comment: `url lib.parse.parse_qs()`

Comment: Thanks @RobRaymond I had a go with urllib but it seemed to not be recognising this as a bit of URL because it doesn't start with http/s. Is that right or do I need to persevere with it? Also, my issue isn't parsing the string, it's getting the sections into the right columns.

Answer (score 1):

All the utilities you need are already in place

- `urllib.parse.parse_qs()` generates a `dict` from a URL query string
- constructor of `DataFrame()`
- further expand parameters that are not part of standard URL parsing

```
df = pd.DataFrame(urllib.parse.parse_qs("flt=promotionflag%3A1%3Borganicfilter%3AOrganic&sortBy=MOST_POPULAR"))

# expand out parameters semi-colon delimited
df = (df
 .assign(flt=df.flt.str.split(";"))
 .explode("flt")
 .reset_index(drop=True)
)
# change colon delimited into key/value columns
df = df.join(df.flt.apply(lambda s: {"key":s.split(":")[0], "value":s.split(":")[1]}).apply(pd.Series))
```

|  | flt | sortBy | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | promotionflag:1 | MOST_POPULAR | promotionflag | 1 |
| 1 | organicfilter:Organic | MOST_POPULAR | organicfilter | Organic |

Comment: Any way of parsing out the different filters to separate columns?